# How to link fullcalendar and google api in react js

Tags: reactjs, google-api, fullcalendar

I want to bring a customized full calnedar and connect it with Google canlander api, but I don't know because it's customized Help me

The full calendar site says we can apply the code below, but I don't know where to put the code.

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ googleCalendarPlugin ],
  googleCalendarApiKey: '<YOUR API KEY>',
  events: {
    googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com',
    className: 'gcal-event' // an option!
  }
});
```

Below is my current code.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./style.module.css";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Button,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Container
} from "reactstrap";
import Select from "react-select";
import DateRangePicker from "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker";
import googleCalendarPlugin from "@fullcalendar/google-calendar"; //google calendar api
import "./custom.module.css";
import events from "./events";
import CustomModal from "../Components/CustomModal";


let todayStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, "");
export default function Calendar() {
  const [weekendsVisible, setWeekendsVisible] = useState(true);
  const [currentEvents, setCurrentEvents] = useState([]);
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [confirmModal, setConfirmModal] = useState(false);
  const calendarRef = useRef(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [start, setStart] = useState(new Date());
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(new Date());
  

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    handleClose();
    setModal(false);
  };
    function handleDateClick(arg) {
    };
  function handleDateSelect(selectInfo) {
    if (
      selectInfo.view.type === "timeGridWeek" ||
      selectInfo.view.type === "timeGridDay"
      ) {
        selectInfo.view.calendar.unselect();
        setState({ selectInfo, state: "create" });
        // Open modal create
        console.log("open modal create");
        // console.log(selectInfo);
        setStart(selectInfo.start);
        setEnd(selectInfo.end);
      setModal(true);
    }
  }
  function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
    return (
      <div>
        <i
          style={{
            
            whiteSpace: "nowrap", 
            overflow: "hidden", 
            textOverflow: "ellipsis" 
          }}
        >
          {eventInfo.event.title}
        </i>
      </div>
    );
  }
  function handleEventClick(clickInfo) {
    setState({ clickInfo, state: "update" });
    setTitle(clickInfo.event.title);
    setStart(clickInfo.event.start);
    setEnd(clickInfo.event.end);
    setModal(true);
  }
  function handleEvents(events) {
    setCurrentEvents(events);
  }
  function handleEventDrop(checkInfo) {
    setState({ checkInfo, state: "drop" });
    setConfirmModal(true);
  }
  function handleEventResize(checkInfo) {
    setState({ checkInfo, state: "resize" });
    setConfirmModal(true);
  }
  function handleEdit() {

    state.clickInfo.event.setStart(start);
    state.clickInfo.event.setEnd(end);
    state.clickInfo.event.mutate({
      standardProps: { title }
    });
    handleClose();
  }
  function handleSubmit() {
    const newEvent = {
      id: nanoid(),
      title,
      start: state.selectInfo?.startStr || start.toISOString(),
      end: state.selectInfo?.endStr || end.toISOString(),
      allDay: state.selectInfo?.allDay || false
    };
    

    calendarApi.addEvent(newEvent);
    handleClose();
  }
  function handleDelete() {
    state.clickInfo.event.remove();
    handleClose();
  }
  function handleClose() {
    setTitle("");
    setStart(new Date());
    setEnd(new Date());
    setState({});
    setModal(false);
  }
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([
    { value: "1", label: "All" },
    { value: "2", label: "BPA Technical" },
    { value: "3", label: "Aqua 2 Cleaning" }
  ]);

  function onFilter(element) {
    console.log(element.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Row style={{ marginTop: 150 }}>
          <h1 style={{color:'white', textAlign:'center', marginBottom:50}}>Make a Booking</h1>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col md={12}>
            <FullCalendar
              ref={calendarRef}
              plugins={[dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
              headerToolbar={{
                left: "prev,today,next",
                center: "title",
                right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
              }}
              buttonText={{  
                today: "Today's Time Table",
                month: "month",
                week: "week",
                day: "day",
                list: "list"
              }}
              initialView="timeGridWeek"
              editable={true}
              selectable={true}
              selectMirror={true}
              dayMaxEvents={true}
              weekends={weekendsVisible}
              //
              initialEvents={[
                
                {
                },

                {
                  id: nanoid(),
                  title: "All-day event",
                  start: todayStr
                },
                {
                  id: nanoid(),
                  title: "Timed event",
                  start: todayStr + "T12:00:00",
                  end: todayStr + "T12:30:00"
                 
                }
              ]} 
              select={handleDateSelect}
              eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
              eventClick={handleEventClick}
              eventsSet={() => handleEvents(events)}
              eventDrop={handleEventDrop}
              eventResize={handleEventResize}
              //
              dateClick={handleDateClick}
              eventAdd={(e) => {
                console.log("eventAdd", e);
              }}
              eventChange={(e) => {
                console.log("eventChange", e);
              }}
              eventRemove={(e) => {
                console.log("eventRemove", e);
              }}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>

      <CustomModal
        title={state.state === "update" ? "Update Booking" : "Make a Booking"}
        isOpen={modal}
        toggle={handleCloseModal}
        onCancel={handleCloseModal}
        onSubmit={state.clickInfo ? handleEdit : handleSubmit}
        submitText={state.clickInfo ? "Update" : "Save"}
        onDelete={state.clickInfo && handleDelete}
        deleteText="Delete"
      >
        <FormGroup>
          <Label for="@gmail.com">Trainer</Label>
          <br/>
          <select className="form-control" name="title" 
          value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}>
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
          </select>

         
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <Label for="@gmail.com">Start Time - End Time</Label>
          <DateRangePicker
            initialSettings={{
              locale: {
                format: "M/DD hh:mm A"
              },
              startDate: start,
              endDate: end,
              timePicker: true
            }}
            onApply={(event, picker) => {
              
              setStart(new Date(picker.startDate));
              setEnd(new Date(picker.endDate));
            }}
          >
            <input className="form-control" type="text" />
          </DateRangePicker>
        </FormGroup>
      </CustomModal>

      <CustomModal
        title={state.state === "resize" ? "Resize Event" : "Drop Event"}
        isOpen={confirmModal}
        toggle={() => {
          state.checkInfo.revert();
          setConfirmModal(false);
        }}
        onCancel={() => {
          state.checkInfo.revert();
          setConfirmModal(false);
        }}
        cancelText="Cancel"
        onSubmit={() => setConfirmModal(false)}
        submitText={"OK"}
      >
        Do you want to {state.state} this event?
      </CustomModal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to apply the code below to my code by applying calendar id and api key on Google, but I don't know.

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ googleCalendarPlugin ],
  googleCalendarApiKey: '<YOUR API KEY>',
  events: {
    googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com',
    className: 'gcal-event' // an option!
  }
});
```

Comment: Api key will only give you access to public data did you set the calendar to public?

Comment: Those snippets are fullCalendar options. In React they should go inside the `<FullCalendar` tag where you've also put all the other calendar options already.

Comment: Yes, I set it to public.
Should I put the code you answered in the calendar.js file and execute it?

Comment: If your calender is public then you don't need DalmTo's code

Comment: please edit your question and include the full error message

Comment: Where is declaration for ' calendarApi ', that you are using in handleSubmit function ? Prob. this code doesn't work ...